# How to use Persian Calendar in Syncfusion.SfCalendar.android xamarin controls

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion.SfCalendar.android in Xamarin to show a Persian Calendar in the application (for Android). To use Hijri calendar, I've the "locale" as follows:

```
calendar.Locale = new Java.Util.Locale("FA", "IR");
```

But unfortunately, month names are not changed. (although week names changed approprietly)

Comment: What do you mean by "names are not changed"!?